# Mongodb aggregate, convert subdocument array to a single object

Tags: mongodb

My document

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "5f3d0f13fd6fd6667f8f56d6",
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": "5f3d0f16fd6fd6667f8f5813",
        "d": "2019-09-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        "h": 197
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f3d0f16fd6fd6667f8f5814",
        "d": "2019-09-23T00:00:00.000Z",
        "h": 196,
      },
      {
        "_id": "5f3d0f16fd6fd6667f8f5815",
        "d": "2019-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        "h": 194,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output

```
{
  "_id": "5f3d0f13fd6fd6667f8f56d6",
  t: [1386493512, 1386493572, 1386493632, 1386493692], //unix timestamps
  h: [197, 196, 194]
}
```

How do I do this conversion with MongoDB aggregate framework?

Probably something with `$unwind` `$push`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$unwind` but can use `$project`.

Note you can't get a unix timestamp out-of-the-box, but you need to manage the operation by yourself using the [mongo date expression operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expression-operators).

EDIT: added [$toLong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495026/3309466) step

In this example, you will get a `Date` object as output that will be easily transformed to a timestamp in the client who runs the query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      t: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items.d",
          as: "dateval",
          in: {
            $toLong: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$$dateval"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      h: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items.h",
          as: "intval",
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$intval",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f3d0f13fd6fd6667f8f56d6",
    "h": [
      197,
      196,
      194
    ],
    "t": [
      NumberLong(1568937600000),
      NumberLong(1569196800000),
      NumberLong(1569283200000)
    ]
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/D1mDDNj5fJ1

Comment: You think this query has much better perfomance than just modify the dataset directly in my client (nodejs)? I find this aggregate framework hard to grasp.

Comment: This aggregation would be simple to perform and the hardware of the mongodb is for sure more performant for these simple `$map` operation. Morover in this sync case, nodejs would block the eventloop so for big dataset it could be a bottleneck if you are running an HTTP server

Comment: consider that `$unwind` force mongo to load the data in memory and process them instead, a `$projection` instead will be a transform stream in the cursor and won't need additional memory footprint

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So you're saying this answer is better than the one below?

Comment: Yes, you can verify it executing `db.collection.explain().aggregate(..`. This query has `"optimizedPipeline" : true,` and only 1 stage, the other one 3 stages instead.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon is right $unwind is little expensive for memory. but my thinking its depends on number of users on your project and usage of features and types of query requirement.

Comment: I execute this query while I zoom in trading chart. Maybe 5 request per seconds. So memory in and performance is crucial in this case. But your answer is cleaner.

Comment: @Joe yup so this is the best answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `items` array
- `$group` by _id and push `h` in to `h`
- convert string date to ISODate using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) and convert ISODate to timestamp using [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      h: { $push: "$items.h" },
      t: {
        $push: {
          $toLong: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$items.d" } }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_WqwRBftj29)